# xtype and itemId properties missing in custom ExtJS component

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, parent-child, custom-component

I created a custom ExtJS by extending `Ext.container.Container` comprising of controls like `radiofield`, `combo` and a `dataview` and named its `alias` config as `widget.CustomerDetail`.

In the actual View, I'm using this component by defining it in `items` array as follows.

```
{
    xtype: 'CustomerDetail',
    itemId: 'customerDetail',
    customerId: '<some id>', //this is custom attribute that I access in CustomerDetail's constructor.
    listeners: {
        'customerDataChanged': function(sender, eOpts) {
            //This event is fired from CustomerDetail's components' change events
            //by this.fireEvent("customerDataChanged", obj, eOpts);
            //Do something like enabling Parent form's Save button.
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm unable to query this custom component in its parent view (the form which uses it) by using `this.getComponent('<parent_form_itemId').getComponent('customerDetail')`.

while, if I just inspect `this.getComponent('<parent_form_itemId')`, it has whole form object, and its `items` array also has `CustomerDetail` component, but surprisingly `CustomerDetail`s object doesn't have `xtype` or `itemId` present in it.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a child component with [down()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-down):

```
this.down('#customerDetail');
```

Do not forget the # when you select by itemId.

Comment: As I said, `xtype` and `itemId` properties itself were not present in the component's object. And bizarrely, it was due the use of `constructor` method in `CustomerDetail` itself, I removed it and itemId and xtype both turned in the object. Still not understanding why it happened.